# Number of rows in section error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, rows

I have a tableview with two custom-cell xibs.

The first xib only contains uilabel and the second one only uibutton.

Once the uibutton is clicked the `someTagsArray` (array which i use for count in numberOfRows function) is appended and new rows should be inserted, but instead i'm getting this nasty error

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Here is my code (numberOfRowsInSection)

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->    
Int {
        return someTagsArray.count + 1
    }
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

        if(indexPath.row < someTagsArray.count){
            var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

            cell.lblCarName.text = linesmain["start"]![indexPath.row]

            return cell

        } else {
          var celle:vwAnswers = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! vwAnswers
            celle.Answer1.setTitle(answersmain["start"]![0], forState:UIControlState.Normal)

// answertitle is a global string variable                

            answertitle1 = "\(celle.Answer1.currentTitle!)"

            return celle

        }}
```

and finally the function code which crashes the app

```
func insertData(){

// appending the array to increase count

    someTagsArray += linesmain[answertitle1]!

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let insertedIndexPathRange = 0..<self.linesmain[answertitle2]!.count-4
    var insertedIndexPaths = insertedIndexPathRange.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) }
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: You should write tableView.beginUpdates() before appending anything into someTagsArray.

Comment: @Nishant it returns the same error, now with bigger margin `number of rows after the update (11) against original (4)`

Comment: Then the error must be in method call      insertRowsAtIndexPaths. You exception description says: 0 inserted, 0 deleted. This means that the insert function is inserting 0 rows, while the someTagsArray.count has increased. Hence the error.

Comment: @Nishant that sounds reasonable. But how do i insert the rows correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for inserting rows:

```
func insertData(){

    let initialCount = someTagsArray.count as Int
    let newObjects = linesmain[answertitle1] as! NSArray

    // appending the array to increase count        
    //someTagsArray += newObjects
    someTagsArray.addObjectsFromArray(newObjects)


    self.tableView!.beginUpdates()

    var insertedIndexPaths: NSMutableArray = []

    for var i = 0; i < newObjects.count; ++i {
        insertedIndexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: initialCount+i, inSection: 0))
    }

    self.tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    self.tableView!.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: returns the following error `The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (4 inserted, 0 deleted)`

Comment: just checked checked - unfortunately, `binary operator += cannot be applied to NSArray type of objects`.

Comment: checked again. `array doesn't have a member named addObjectsFromArrays`. wasn't it deprecated in swift 1.2 ?

Comment: You can use `someTagsArray.addObjectsFromArray(newObjects)` instead. OR you can change the datatype for `newObjects` to `Array` in order to use the binary operator (+=).

Comment: thank you. changed the type from NSArray to simple Array and the appending worked! but the issue is - it loads inside the already loaded rows. i want it to load after the last row - at the bottom.

Comment: change the for loop to this `for var i = 0; i < newObjects.count; ++i {
        insertedIndexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: someTagsArray.count+i, inSection: 0))
    }`

Comment: unfortunately, it crashes ( reason: `attempt to insert row 7 into section 0, but there are only 7 rows in section 0 after the update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88107/discussion-between-nishant-and-david-robertson).